# The conversion from csv to binary format reduces the file size abnormally

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have `csv` dataset of size `5.2`GB (Taken from [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/HEPMASS)). It has about 7M rows of `dimension = 29`. The values are of type `float64`. I want to convert this dataset into a binary file. To do so, I do the following simple lines:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',')
np.asarray(df.values).tofile('data_binary.dat')
```

A snapshot of the data looks like this:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00,9.439358860254287720e-02,1.275558676570653915e-02,9.119330644607543945e-01,-9.083136916160583496e-02,-2.335745543241500854e-01,-1.054220795631408691e+00,-9.759366512298583984e-01,-1.067278265953063965e+00,-6.138502955436706543e-01,7.542607188224792480e-01,-9.256605505943298340e-01,-5.289512276649475098e-01,1.235263347625732422e+00,8.606486320495605469e-01,-2.320102453231811523e-01,-4.043335020542144775e-01,-1.559396624565124512e+00,-8.154401183128356934e-01,-1.376865267753601074e+00,6.759096682071685791e-02,1.372575879096984863e+00,-5.736824870109558105e-01,-1.368692040443420410e+00,-4.793794453144073486e-01,1.529256343841552734e+00,-5.757816433906555176e-01,-1.290232419967651367e+00,4.999999694824218750e+02
1.000000000000000000e+00,3.272003531455993652e-01,-2.395536154508590698e-01,-1.592038273811340332e+00,-2.324983835220336914e+00,-5.070934891700744629e-01,1.574625492095947266e+00,-1.050106048583984375e+00,9.686639308929443359e-01,1.312386870384216309e+00,7.542607188224792480e-01,-9.113077521324157715e-01,-1.718587398529052734e+00,3.751282095909118652e-01,8.606486320495605469e-01,-3.711451292037963867e-01,-5.625200271606445312e-01,-2.721544206142425537e-01,-8.154401183128356934e-01,-3.339428007602691650e-01,1.058411240577697754e+00,4.364815354347229004e-01,-5.736824870109558105e-01,-2.172690257430076599e-02,-5.791836977005004883e-01,-3.260441124439239502e-01,-2.024624943733215332e-01,-4.585579931735992432e-01,7.500000000000000000e+02
```

The new binary file `data_binary.dat` is reduced to `1.5`GB. This is a huge reduction which made me wonder if something went wrong with the way I use to convert `csv` to binary format. Is this reduction expected? At least this much?

Comment: It can easily be like this. As a csv, data is *text*. So something like `44.1232310` will require *ten bytes*, but only 4/8 bytes depending on your numeric data-types. Can you give an example of your data?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. I have updated my post

Comment: But what does the actual csv look like? What does `df.values.dtype` give you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, so I went and downloaded a sample of the data. Each row is something like:

```
0.000000000000000000e+00,9.439358860254287720e-02,1.275558676570653915e-02 ...
```

Each individual number seems to have 25 character overall, and actually, 26 or so if you include the comma. So that's one byte per character, so about 25 bytes. Using a binary representation of a 64-bit floating point numbers will require ... 64 bits i.e. 8 bytes per number. So You should expect the binary file to be less than 1/3 the size, so this seems correct:

5.2/3 = 1.73...

A better estimate would be about 26 characters per number (including commas and line-breaks), so:

```
In [2]: (8/26)*5.2
Out[2]: 1.6
```

Seems legit.

Comment: MAke sense. Well explained. Thank you

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I understand from your answer that data is stored directly as binary instead of text (csv) which would store each of these 25 characters in separate char memory.  I thought some compression was involved, i guess not, its just storage.  1.  Wish to correct my understanding.  2.  What if the data was only text? I guess the difference wont be huge.

Comment: I don't understand your second question, but as to your first, no compression is done on text files unless you do. Indeed, the file the OP is referring to is made available on the web in a compressed format. But fundamentally, the *binary* representation isn't of the *text*, because using `pandas`, the data was converted to a 64bit floating point array. It is no longer text, it has an entirely different represenation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you. I understand better now.  My second question was - if data is only characters like "ABasdasd", say alpha GUID likes of 25 char - in that case, I guess I will be better off using the standard text based data types.  The kind of memory saving we see in the above context works well when the data itself can be represented as a number (64bit floating point array).  I ask this to know - which cases we should use text type.  And which cases binary.