# Why does a dataframe occupy more memory than the size of file it came from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, memory

I have a txt file which is 487MB in size. However, when I create a dataframe out of this text file, it occupies a little more than 2.5GB in memory. Could anyone explain why this happens ?

```
>>>df=pd.read_csv('mytxtfile.txt', sep=',')

>>>sys.getsizeof(df)
2743190253
```

Comment: there could be very many reasons. Without looking at your data, we cannot tell you why *exactly* but why do you expect it to occupy less/more?

Comment: I don't know exactly where the extra size comes from (I presume it's the general overhead of storing data in columns and rows, though I'm sure some smarter SO people could comment better on that); however, the general rule-of-thumb with handling `pandas` dataframes is to always have 5-10 times the size of the data available in memory. That rule seems to hold true for your case here as well.

Comment: depending on your data, it could be possible. For example, if I import a file with a lot of `0,1` and missing, each is either 0 or 1 byte in the `txt`, but 4 or 8 bytes in data (32 or 64 bit integer/float).

Comment: @QuangHoang: Makes sense. I was continuously running into Memory errors while working on files of sizes 300MB - 1.5GB. It's only when I checked the size of df in memory I realized why this was happening!

Comment: Note this can happen the other way around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309668/the-conversion-from-csv-to-binary-format-reduces-the-file-size-abnormally/50309835#50309835 Fundamentally, your csv is *text*, and there's no reason why a text-based format should be larger or smaller than whatever it is going to become when you deserialize that text and materialize some data-structure in memory.