# How can a csv that is 3.6 gb take up all my memory of 64gb

Tags: python, pandas

I am loading in a csv into a pandas dataframe. The csv is 3.6 gb and I have 64 gb of ram. How is it possible that the memory exceeds 64 gb when loading a 3.6 gb file?

Is there a better way to load the entire dataframe that does not take up so much memory or perhaps there is something wrong with my computer.

Here is the code I am using to load the csv

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/ML_DATA.csv')
```

I could also provide the csv file if that is of interest.

Here is a sample of what the data looks like

```
df = pd.read_csv('../input/ML_DATA.csv', nrows=10)
df.shape -> (10, 4247)
```

Here is a screen shot

[image]

Here is a print of `df.info()`

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 3 entries, 0 to 2
Columns: 4247 entries, Location+Type to Pct of housing units in 4+ unit buildings
dtypes: float64(1132), int64(3), object(3112)
memory usage: 99.7+ KB
None
```

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to load the csv?

Comment: Could you please share the code, maybe you load correctly your code but during the execution of your script, you are copying the data several times,  Think also about in run your data per parts, clean your data, and change the type of data.

Comment: Can you share a row of your csv? Small integers and floats can take less space as csv than 64bit number types. String columns can be converted to categorical data to save space.

Comment: @Zakk I updated my code, I could also share the csv if that is of interest.

Comment: @justanewb I don't think sharing the CSV in its entirety will be any help, but if you can share a small sample that's a good representation of the entire set, that would be a big help.

Comment: @Slbox Would you like a few of the raw rows?

Comment: pandas has a few ways to profile and handle large data sets. Depending on what you're planning to do with your dataframe, it could be enough. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/scale.html

Comment: What is the process memory limit on your system?

Comment: @JimD I uploaded a shot of my system, does that work?

Comment: **Because integer or float columns with any NAs take 32 bytes to store, in pandas.** Show us `df.info()`, then you can how much memory each column takes up. Post that into your question. We don't need the htop screenshot, just delete it. Show us `df.info()`. After you figure out which columns take lots of memory, we can discuss how to handle that (slicing unnecessary columns, chunking by rows, dropping/filling NA rows only where safe to, etc.)

Comment: @smci I did but there is alot of columns so thats the only thing that prints, is there a way of seeing more?

Comment: Divide and conquer; ave you tried try successively halving the size of your enormous CSV until you get a size that loads?

Comment: @balmy No, I have not.

Comment: Your file is *text*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Most of it should be floating point, how would I convert them as I read?

Comment: Set `pd.options.display.max_info_columns = 100` or whatever then dump `df.info()` again. Or to see all 4247 columns: [`df.info(max_cols=9999)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.info.html)

Comment: Related if you want to understand why text representation can be more memory efficient than numpy numeric types or, even worse, python object types: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309668/the-conversion-from-csv-to-binary-format-reduces-the-file-size-abnormally/50309835#50309835

Comment: It's being converted as you read, but a text representation can be more efficient (but less accurate)

Comment: **Cut down the number of rows loaded, with [`pd.read_csv(..., nrows=1e5)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html?highlight=nrows%20usecols).** And to cut down the columns, you could use [`pd.read_csv(..., usecols=range(0,150))`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). Please see the doc.

Comment: @justanewb.  Actually a "ulimit -a" and look for the "max memory size" and the "virtual memory" limits.  Then a "free" (on Linux) or "sysctl hw.physmem" (on BSD) The results would confirm if the solution by vy32 is correct, which I suspect it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with your computer. You are experiencing the overhead associated with storing the data.

Each of these values is probably being stored as a 64-bit value inside your computer, but a column that is stored as a string is being stored as a python object, which is going to be more like 240 bytes per cell.

So drop the columns you don’t need, enable swapping, and if you want to get really fancy, learn how to use Dask.

Also, as an aside, if you put this whole table into a SQLlite3 database, it will be a lot easier.